# Why is bison include not applying/extending to union%?

Tags: c, import, boolean, bison, flex-lexer

So here is the start of my program. I keep getting the error
boolExpr.y:13:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
bool boolean;
However when I check the bison generated file, I can see stdbool.h is included at the start of the program executing. I can't figure out how a library can be important but then bool not be recognized. I'm thinking I missed something simple, or I need to reinstall bison or lex. I can include the rest of the program if needed.

I tried to switch it to int boolean; instead of bool boolean; and that fixed the compilation problem, however it still mystifies me.
Is there some way to extend a pointer to a struct into %union without getting compile errors? I tried to make a structName * boolean; to replace bool boolean but that kept coming back as undefined wimplicit error as well.

```
%{
#include "semantics.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "IOMngr.h"
#include <string.h>
extern int yylex(); /* The next token function. */
extern char *yytext; /* The matched token text. */
extern int yyerror(char *s);
extern SymTab *table;
extern SymEntry *entry; 
%}
%union{
 bool boolean;(this is the line # of error)
 char * string;
}
%type <string> Id
%type <boolean> Expr
%type <boolean> Term
%type <boolean> Factor
%token Ident
%token TRUE
%token FALSE
%token OR
%token AND
%%
Prog : StmtSeq {printSymTab();};
StmtSeq : Stmt StmtSeq { };
StmtSeq : { };
Stmt : Id '=' Expr ';' {storeVar($1, $3);};
Expr : Expr OR Term {$$ = doOR($1, $3);};
Expr : Term {$$ = $1;};
Term : Term AND Factor {$$ = doAND($1, $3);};
Term : Factor {$$ = $1;};
Factor : '!' Factor {$$ = doNOT($2);};
Factor : '(' Expr ')' {$$ = $2;};
Factor : Id {$$ = getVal($1);};
Factor : TRUE {$$ = true;};
Factor : FALSE {$$ = false;};
Id : Ident {$$ = strdup(yytext);};
%%
int yyerror(char *s) {
 WriteIndicator(getCurrentColumnNum());
 WriteMessage("Illegal Character in YACC");
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've rerun `bison`  after adding that `#include <stdbool.h>`?!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, silly mistake after all- in my lex file, I had

```
#include "h4.tab.h"
#include "SymTab.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
```

but it should have been

```
#include "SymTab.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "h4.tab.h"
```

didn't realize include order mattered!

Comment: As best practice, you should always put standard library includes first unless you have a really good reason not to (and that reason should be documented in a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `%union` declaration, Bison creates a `union` type called `YYSTYPE` which it declares in the generated header file; that type is used in the declaration of `yylval`, which is also in the generated header file. Putting the declarations in the generated header file means that you don't need to do anything to make `yylval` and its type `YYSTYPE` available in your lexical analyser, other than `#include`ing the bison-generated header file.

That's fine if all the types referred to in the `%union` declaration are standard C types. But there is a problem if you want to use a type which requires an `#include`d header file, or which you yourself define. Assuming you put the necessary lines in a bison code prologue (`%{...}%`) before the `%union` declaration, you won't have a problem compiling your parser, but you will run into a problem in the lexical analyser. When you `#include` your header file, you will effectively insert the declaration of ´union YYSTYPE´ and that will fail unless all of the referenced types have already been defined.

Of course, you can solve this issue by just copying all the necessary `#include`s and/or definitions from the `.y` file to the `.l` file, making sure that you put the ones needed for the `union+` declaration *before* the `#include` of the header file and the ones which require `YYSTYPE` be defined *after* the `#include`. But that violates the principles of good software design; it means that every time you change an `#include` or declaration in your `.y` file, you need to think about whether and where you need to make a similar change in your `.l` file. Fortunately, bison provides a more convenient mechanism.

The ideal would be to arrange for everything needed to be inserted into the generated header file. Then you can just `#include "h4.tab.h"` in the lexical analyzer, confident that you don't need to do anything else to ensure that needed `#include`s are present and in the correct order.

To this end, Bison provides a more flexible alternative to `%{...}%`, the `%code` directive:

```
%code [where] {
// code to insert
}
```

There are a few possible values for `where`, which are documented in the [Bison documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#g_t_0025code-Summary).
Two of these are used to maintain the generated header file:

- `%code requires { ... }` inserts the code block in both the header file and the source file, in both cases before the `union` declaration. This is the code block type you should use for dependencies of the semantic and location types.
- `%code provides { ... }` also inserts the code block into both the header and the source file, but this time *after*  the `union` declaration. You can use this block type if you have some interfaces which themselves refer to `YYSTYPE`.

You can still use `%{...}%` to insert code directly into the output source code. But you might want to instead use

```
* %code { ... }
```

which, like `%{...}%`, only inserts the code in the source file. Unlike `%{...}%`, it inserts the code in a defined place in the source file, after the `YYSTYPE` and other declarations. This avoids obscure problems with `%{...}%` blocks, which are sometimes inserted early and sometimes inserted late and therefore can suddenly fail to compile if you change the order of apparently unrelated bison directives.